# How does the Damage Conversion knack work?

Tags: damage, scion

We're not quite sure how the Epic Stamina knack Damage Conversion works. Let's say I take 22 lethal damage from an attack, and I soak 11 lethal and 13 bashing. Do I:

- Spend a point of legend to convert the 22 lethal to 22 bashing, soak 13, and thus take 9 bashing damage?

or:

- Soak 11 lethal, spend a point of legend to convert the remaining 11 lethal to 11 bashing, then soak all 11 of that, taking no damage?

Both seem to be valid interpretations; one is only useful if you have a lot more bashing soak than lethal (or if you want to be unconscious rather than dead), but the other seems ridiculously powerful. But then, this is Scion, where ridiculously powerful is the name of the game...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Damage is resolved all at once**

That is, damage is dealt, compared against soak, and then resolved, in that order. Damage Conversion converts *all* of the damage from an attack from lethal to bashing. That bashing is then compared against soak, reduced appropriately, and then applied to health.

Thus, in your example you would end up taking 9 bashing damage.